# [Facebook][Graph-API] Cannot access some public profile informations with the 2.9 graph

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I've got two basic Facebook applications, one created with the `v2.8` graph api version, and the new one created with the `v2.9` version of the graph api (as described in the apps dashboards: https://developers.facebook.com/apps/{id}/dashboard/)

The last application using the `v2.9` graph api seems to not being able to request user public profile information. But the one using the `2.8` is able to do it, even with the `2.9` api version.

Both apps have the same parameters:
- age restriction: 13+
- country restriciton: no
- alcohol: no

#### Able to access public information using the first app

https://graph.facebook.com/v2.9/123456789?access_token={app1_id}|{app1_secret}

```
{
    "name": "Name of the guy",
    "id": "123456789"
}
```

#### Error while trying to access public information using the second app

https://graph.facebook.com/v2.9/123456789?access_token={app2_id}|{app2_secret}

```
{
    "error": {
        "message": "Unsupported get request. Object with ID '123456789' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api",
        "type": "GraphMethodException",
        "code": 100,
        "fbtrace_id": "CQ9V460Jycd"
    }
}
```

Still, I can access profile information of some users with this app like Mark Zuckerberg and so on.
So it seems that my second app doesn't have the right permissions for this profile. But I can't figure why, because:
 - the user profile I'm requesting doesn't have any link with my app
 - I'm trying to access `public_profile` data which is a default given authorization.

Is it possible for a user to limit the api version which can access to his public profile information?
How could I debug that? Is there a way to find out if a user profile is restricted for a specific api version?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: No, this is simply is because user ids are app-scoped since API v2.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As answered by CBroe, user id are scoped by applications since Facebook graph v2.0.

This means that an `user id` get from one application doesn't necessarily exist with another application (however, for some profile, it could exist...).

If you want to use multiple application and do a link between users:

- you have to group your applications using a "Business manager" https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/business-manager#create-business
- users have to be logged in with each of your apps